# Can I call multiple FFMPEG processes on a multi-core LAMP machine from PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, multicore

I am using PHP to call an FFMPEG command using exec(). The script that initiates this command is called from another PHP script using

```
proc_close(proc_open('php /phpdirectory/process.php &', array(), $foo));
```

This works great. The ffmpeg command is called and runs 'in the background' leaving the first script to return to the user and in this case carry on uploading files. What if I am using a machine with multiple cores? How would I go about optimizing things so that I could call an ffmpeg process for each core? Or will a multicore machine process split the work between cores anyway and get through a single process faster?

Anyone?

Comment: CentOS, I am running an Amazon EC2 instance and wondering how my setup will change if I used larger instances. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheduling of the FFMPEG process is done by the kernel scheduler. You can't explicitly fire your processes at each core.

Answer (score 0):

blairyeah is right that it's not an optimisation, but you can in fact pin a process to a specific CPU using [`taskset(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset).

Solution found in [a ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/335392/47979).